# with python: Find files and copy to another directory

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying, os.walk

The directory tree looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS9Vx.png

My goal is to enter the member ID and the program should analyze the associated files (activities.json) from all days and copy all these files into a new directory. I also want to rename the copied files (1,2,3,4 .....), but I get an error.

Normally I shouldn't get the error because the copied files will have different names ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ...... )

code:

```
import os
import json
import win32com.client as win32 # pip install pywin32
import shutil

rootDir = 'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Linkedin/linkedin_hb_ma'
x = 1

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if dirName.endswith("1eb95ebb-d87d-Xd7-8c84-Xc"):
        for file in fileList:
            abs_path = os.path.join(dirName, file)
            if file.endswith("activities.json"):
                print('Found directory:'+ abs_path)
                src = abs_path
                dst = 'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Linkedin analyze/tableau bsp/1/3'
                shutil.copy(src, dst)
                m = str(x)
                print(m)
                os.rename('C:/Users/A.Abboudi/Desktop/Linkedin analyze/tableau bsp/1/3/activities.json', m)
                x =x+ 1
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-5491807f76ee> in <module>
     20                 m = str(x)
     21                 print(m)
---> 22                 os.rename(abs_path, m)
     23                 x += 1
"FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists"
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: Can you please post a full error? do you get any line numbers there??

Comment: @DeepBhatt done

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the folder already? has it already changed your filename once? try to delete any created file on dest folder!

if that's not the case then try this:

code

```
if not os.path.exists("name of folder/file"):
    os.rename('C:/Users/A.Abboudi/Desktop/Linkedin analyze/tableau bsp/1/3/activities.json', m)
```

Don't try to copy from here because I'm not sure on this identation!